# CakePhp 2.0 Strange Redirect

Tags: cakephp, mod-rewrite

Everything fine for all urls like `/mydomain/<controller>/` which normally redirect to `/mydomain/<controller>/<index>`.

Except one, `/mydomain/users` it does not redirect (read rewrite) to `/mydomain/users/index` but to `/mydomain/app/webroot/users`

Why?

Comment: Since you use both terms - are you talking about redirects or url rewrite?

Answer (score 1):

Very simple:
in the webroot directory there was a folder named users.
Deleted it, and it is working back again.